# how to display the image in flutter which I have stored in sqlite database

Tags: flutter, sqflite

This is dart file minimum code where user selects and saves photo of the customer through gallery or camera.
This code works fine. It saves the path of image in database.
When user clicks on the particular customer from the list I want to diplay the customer image stored in database in next screen. I dont know how to retrieve the stored image from database and display it. Can anyone help me plzz. Stuck with this for 2 days.

Add_person.dart

```
PickedFile _imageFile;
final ImagePicker _picker=ImagePicker();

void getImage(ImageSource source) async{
   final pickedFile=await _picker.getImage(
       source:source);
        setState(() {
          _imageFile=pickedFile;
          addCustomer.custPhoto = _imageFile.path;
    });
  }

 Widget ImageProfile(){
    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 80.0,
            backgroundImage: _imageFile==null?AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
                :FileImage(File(_imageFile.path)),

          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 4,
                    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  ),
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (builder)=>bottomSheet());
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget bottomSheet(){
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal:20,
          vertical:20,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Choose profile photo",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                  onPressed: (){
                    getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                  },
                  icon:Icon(Icons.camera,color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,), label:Text("camera")),
              FlatButton.icon(
                  onPressed: (){
                    getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                  },
                  icon:Icon(Icons.photo_library), label:Text("Gallery"))
            ],

          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note_info.dart  //This is where i want to display the image

```
Widget ImageProfile() {
    return Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage:  _imageFile==null?AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
              :FileImage(File(customer.custPhoto,))),

      );

  }
```

database_helper.dart

```
await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE customerDetails (custId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'custName STRING, '
            'mobileNum STRING, company STRING, custPhoto STRING, showOnCall bool,'
            'remindOn STRING,location STRING)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the answer to my question.

```
ImageProfile(customer.custPhoto),
Widget ImageProfile(String fileName) {
    return Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage:  fileName == null
              ?AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
              :FileImage(File(customer.custPhoto))),

      );

  }
```

Actually I didnt need this variables

```
PickedFile _imageFile;
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
```